# Retrieving autogenerated data in insert on ADODataset

Tags: delphi, tadodataset

I actually try to do an insert on a ADODataset linked on a table with an auto-generated GUID.
When I try to get the new ID of my record I get some zero for GUID.

Comment: You will need to save the current bookmark/cursor, use ADODataSet.Requery and restore bookmark/cursor. another option is to try and use `SELECT @@IDENTITY` after the insert (not tested though)

Comment: I tried this solution. But Requery reload all records... no ?
So, it isn't the best practices to obtain the best performances

Comment: You can als initialize the guid to the TAdoDataSet before insert or onnewrecord

Comment: Yes! At the moment it's the solution I've choosen. But I would like know the way to use the SQL autogenerated field. :-)

Comment: @kobik: Don't use @@IDENTITY but SCOPE_IDENTITY when you have triggers

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question but if anyone comes across it...

The big advantage of using GUIDs is that you don't care where they originate from. A value generated as part of a default constraint is no better or worse than a correctly generated GUID in a client program.

@Ravaut123 is correct in that you should just set the GUIDs value when inserting on the TADOataSet set

Comment: I fail to see how my answer should be down voted. If someone is trying to retrieve a server side generated GUID they clearly don't understand the advantages of GUIDs in the first place.